# Check box - not changing boolean value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where a user has to check condition of sales before submit

```
 <%= form_for @order, url: checkout_path do |f| %>                      
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
  <%= f.check_box :cgos_accepted %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

`:cgos_accepted`is an attribute of order which is a boolean and by default it's false.

When the user check the box it has to change the value to true, but it doesn't...

> EDIT >

this is the html when checkbox is checked:

```
<input class="form-check-input boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="true" name="order[cgos_accepted]" id="order_cgos_accepted" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes">
```

I add  my controller maybe something is wrong and I don't see...

```
class Clients::OrdersController < Clients::ApplicationController

    def index
        @orders = Order.all
        @orders = @orders.filter_by_status(params[:status]) if params[:status]
    end

    def show
        @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @order = current_cart.order
        @billing_address = BillingAddress.new
    end

    def create
        @order = current_cart.order
        @order.update_sub_total!
        @order.update_total!
        if @order.update_attributes!(user_id: current_user.id)
        redirect_to new_clients_order_payment_path(@order)
        end
    end

    private

    def order_params
        params.require(:order).permit(:status,  :user_id, :token , :sub_total, :cgos_accepted)
    end
end
```

Comment: Please add what value your are getting for checkbox after submit

Comment: Where should I take this value? if it's is in the console, my  `order.cgos_accepted: false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good you added your controller

In the create action you should change:

```
 def create
    if @order.update_attributes!(order_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
     redirect_to new_clients_order_payment_path(@order)
    end
 end
```

You weren't passing the strong parameters, so it couldn't update

and as Ray suggested, use:

`= f.check_box :cgos_accepted, { class: "class-name", style: "style"}, "check`ed-value", "unchecked-value"

Answer (score 1):

use `f.check_box` as below,

```
= f.check_box :cgos_accepted, { class: "class-name", style: "style"}, "checked-value", "unchecked-value"
```